# How to list all files and their commit SHAs in a repo

Tags: git

My configuration management team asked me to produce a list of all the files included in a release and the SHA of the last commit for each file. I'm trying to figure out how to do that, but I'm not having much success. I tried using the `ls-files` command and got what looked like promising results (just showing one file as an example):

```
serenity:ezdcadmin jarsen$ git ls-files app/views/users/edit.html.erb -s 
100644 e34b0f56f0e2e60393e8bffdbc1abe6e5ef0df54 0   app/views/users/edit.html.erb
```

But when I run the `log` command for the same file, none of the commit SHAs match the one I got using the `ls-files` command.

```
serenity:ezdcadmin jarsen$ git log --oneline app/views/users/edit.html.erb 
9e68c30 Merge differences
bc8accc bootstrap_buttons & sorting/filtering DONE
8aaf2c0 Revised user pages.
0acf2f0 Finished round two of Property pages.
990b262 Finished User flow - list, add, edit, delete
5e3069b Adding edit and delete user pages.
```

I've spent a lot of time looking for this answer and I kinda need to find it and move on. Any help you could give will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd stick with git log:

```
for i in `git ls-files`; do echo -n "$i "; git log -1 --oneline $i; done | cat
```

The hashes you see in the output of of `git ls-files -s` are, I believe, the blob ID, not the commit.

(The `| cat` above is to prevent git from paginating the output to your terminal.  If you're going to redirect the output to a file, don't bother.)

Comment: Thanks Andy, for this answer. It gives me all of the info I need. I just need to work on the formatting a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, heavily based on @AndyRoss work:

```
git ls-files | xargs -I file bash -c "git --no-pager log -1 -z --format=%h file; echo \" file\""
```

Comment: Thanks Colin. Your answer adds some good stuff to Andy's answer (like the --format argument). I'm sure that as soon as I figure out what everything means I'll be a much better git user. Cheers.